# show LightBox (or any JQuery Modal Pop up) before Page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

Ok, so the most stupid question you're gonna read today is up.

What I wanna do is that if some user of mine visits a page (say. www.mysite.com/whatever), I want to show a Lightbox like pop-up, before the page loads, which takes an input in a text box. When a user enters the text (say, "dawg") and press submit, I wanna then open the page (hopefully without page load) with this variable as a GET. So the URL that'd open be

```
www.mysite.com/whatever?var=dawg
```

Lightboxes are itself easy to configure but this specific case is just twisting me. After so much trying, I don't even know how to approach this problem.

Thank you for reading till here.

Best.

Comment: appending parameters without page refresh can be done using history.pushstate but that is supported in html5 capable browsers only ..

Comment: I hope I can get some solution that works in IE8 + plus all browsers. But thanks for your line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `location.href="#?var=dawg"` and send the ajax call, if you want.